# ActiveReport 3 : Add dynamic column for CrossTable

Tags: dynamic, crosstab, calculated-columns, activereports

I am under ActiveReport 3 and I need to create CrossTable with dynamic number of Columns and Rows.

The example given with ActiveReport 3 has put fix columns in design view and it's bad.
There is a solution up there to create real cross table under Active Report 3?

For now I try with these events:

```
_ReportStart
_DataInitialize
_FetchData
```

Answer (score 0):

In ActiveReports you need to dynamically add the columns (fields/textboxes) using code based on your datasource. You can [see this walkthrough](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports6_start.html?arWLKRunTimeLayouts.html) for a detailed example of how to dynamically create a report. The walkthrough does not create a crosstab but it does show how to add fields dynamically. To create a crosstab, you will essentially just add your textboxes onto the report side-by-side and one-after-the-other. One for each column you want in your crosstab.

> NOTE: After GrapeCity's acquisition of Data Dynamics, the Data Dynamics Reports product was later integrated into [ActiveReports](http://activereports.grapecity.com/). The capabilities of Data Dynamics Reports are generally referred to as "Page Report" or "RDL Report" in ActiveReports. As a result ActiveReports now includes native support for cross tab reports with the "Matrix" control. An example of using a Matrix in ActiveReports' Page Reports is [here](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR9/index.html#Matrix%20Reports.html).

Documentation for the older versions of ActiveReports are available on the [Legacy Documentation page](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/docs/legacy/), which is linked from the [main ActiveReports documentation site](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/docs/).

Comment: The walkthrough link is dead since GrapeCity's website got reorganized a while ago. Is there a corresponding link that works?

Comment: Is there a similar help area for older versions of ActiveReports?

Comment: @mbomb007 I added a note and link to the the docs for legacy versions to the answer.